# Checking date field empty in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net

I tried IsNull, IsEmpty, DBNull, IsDBNull to check date field is empty. but showing error 'conversion from type DBNull to type date is not valid'. How to solve this. Help me..
Sushma

Comment: Put the code which you have tried. There is very less detail about your code. Are you using `datareader` or `dataset` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
IsDate(yourDateVariable)
```

IsDate will return false for blank, null(vb.net: nothing), dbnull.